# Getting JSON object titles

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I've tried searching on here, but I can't figure this out.

I'm trying to do an each function that grabs each title of the object, my json is.

```
{"games":{
    "featured": [
        {
            "game_id": "2"
        },
        {
            "game_id": "15",
        }
    ],
    "popular": [
        {
            "game_id": "2"
        }
    ],
    "new": [
        {
            "game_id": "2",
        },
        {
            "game_id": "15",
        },
        {
            "game_id": "1",
        }
    ]
}}
```

My JS is:

```
$.getJSON("apilink", 
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.games, function(i,category){
            alert(category[0]);
        });
});
```

I'm obviously trying to rotate through featured, popular and new. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nested `$.each()` calls to iterate each  array of objects at  `category` : property name of `"games"` property of `data`

```js
var data = {
  "games": {
    "featured": [{
      "game_id": "2"
    }, {
      "game_id": "15",
    }],
    "popular": [{
      "game_id": "2"
    }],
    "new": [{
      "game_id": "2",
    }, {
      "game_id": "15",
    }, {
      "game_id": "1",
    }]
  }
};

$.each(data.games, function(i, category) {
  console.log(i + ":");
  $.each(category, function(key, obj) {
    console.log(obj)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: This makes sense now. Thanks. I can't get game_id though lol.

Comment: Wouldn't that be "obj.game_id"?

Comment: @christopher.web Yes, or `obj["game_id"]`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to get **featured**, **popular**, **new**? You already have your answer, The first argument **i** returns the key of the object, where the second argument returns the value which is **category**.

```
    $.each(data.games, function(i, category) {
        // category is what you are looking for
        alert(JSON.stringify(category));
        //or
        alert(JSON.stringify(data.games[i]));
    });
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This alerts an object 3 times. Not the title.

Comment: So what i actually do is alert(i), that brings back the titles